# for the database question using the mysql and the .net 2.0

Tags: mysql

I have my data in the mysql database but i want to update my database tables without affecting the old data.
and i need the functionality that i can fetch the old data as well as new updated data as and when required in the software according to the date

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do what you describe:

1. Add a datetime column—let's say `INSERTED_DT`—to your database.
2. Populate `INSERTED_DT` with the current datetime on insert and/or on update.  Most DBMSs have some facility to make it easy to do this kind of thing.
3. Write database queries with parameters to extract relevant sections of your database based on `INSERTED_DT`.